# Titanium Appcelerator - How to Pull Remote Data

Tags: php, json, titanium

I'm using the following code to pull data and nothing happens. Here's my PHP CODE.

```
$getall = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE account_id=$id ORDER BY course_id";        
$showall = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $getall); // Run the query.

$json = array(); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($showall) > 0)
{   

while ($row=$showall->fetch_assoc()) {      

        $json[]=array(  
     'logged' => true,
         'pagename'=>$row['pagename'],
        ); 

        } // end while


header("Content-Type: text/json"); 
echo json_encode(array( 'pages'  =>   $json ));   


}
```

And here's my JS CODE that runs the app.

```
sendit.open('GET', 'http://myurl.com/mypages.php');  
sendit.send();
sendit.onload = function(){  
    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);  
    var json = json.pages;  
    var dataArray = [];  
    var pos;    

    for( pos=0; pos < json.length; pos++){  

        dataArray.push({title:'' + json[pos].pagename + ''});  
        // set the array to the tableView  
        tableview.setData(dataArray);  
    };  

};    

var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView({  
});  

currentWin.add(tableview);
```

When I run the app, all I get is a blank table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check you json array length or past the sample json string

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to move `sendit.send();` below `sendit.open`?

Put a log in your onload event to make sure it is being fired at all.

It states in the [docs](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient.onload-property.html) that the onload must be defined before you call open in order for that even to be registered.

Answer (score 0):

You're embedding your array in another array, so on the javascript side it'd be:

```
    dataArray.push({title:'' + json.pages[pos].pagename + ''});  
                                   ^^^^^ - missing level
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have sendit.onload before send it.send.

I would also recommend you to implement sendit.onerror method, as well as intermediate Ti.API.debug(stuff);
You also double the declaration of json, with is working, but not great.

Comment: I changed the order and it did not work. As well, I have the onerror method in the script and it is not giving me an error.

Comment: Do you have a sniffer like wireshark ? Are you able to enter the debug mode ?

Comment: Try :
    `dataArray.push ( Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({title:'' + json[pos].pagename + ''}) );`

Comment: So I guess there is 0 rows in your json.pages. Have you checked the php result with a navigator ? It must be a Json problem more than a Titanium one.